# How to expand flex container outside parent element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to relatively position some flex container, so I set it parent display relative and flex itself - absolute. But the problem is that flex width does not expands outside its relative parent. How to fix this?

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="w-1/3 bg-blue-500 mx-auto my-5 relative p-4">
  <div class="absolute flex flex-wrap border border-red p-4">
    <div class="border-b w-1/2">content super long</div>
    <div class="border-b w-1/2">content super long</div>
    <div class="w-1/2">content super long</div>
    <div class="w-1/2">content super long content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is enough space for flex container to display its content with no line wraps. But it does not so.

I need following result:

[image]

Comment: remove `flex-wrap` class, you are telling it to wrap.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal but then I lost 2-column view, and I need it too.

Comment: every row should be grouped.

Comment: I cant group them because in future I need responsive number of columns, from 1..3.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by changing `position` property of parent element to `static`, In addition to adding another container with `relative position`.

**Example:**

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="w-1/3 bg-blue-500 mx-auto my-5 relative p-4" style="position:static">
  <div class="container" style="position:relative">
    <div style="width:500px;" class="absolute flex flex-wrap border border-red p-4">
      <div class="border-b w-1/2">content super long</div>
      <div class="border-b w-1/2">content super long</div>
      <div class="w-1/2">content super long</div>
      <div class="w-1/2">content super long content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its not the case. Because I need position relative on container, to relatively position its child flexbox.

Comment: @Molfar Sorry my bad, I updated it check it out. I added another container so now you can make the child bigger than it's parent while keeping it relative to it. I hope this solve your problem.

Comment: Its almost my initial example, just with fixed width of flex element. Its not what I need the best. I'm looking for fixing this with dynamic width, depending on content.https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-haibt-jeywl?fontsize=14